# How to change colour for breadcrum nav bar from purple to #d6df23 in php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I was trying to change the colour of the bar below (https://www.milnerbrowne.com/manufacturing-solutions/)

Breadcrumb navbar

[image]

How do I change the colour to say yellow?

I tried editing header file but it doesnt work... any ideas?

Comment: try .breadcrumbs { background: yellow !important }; in header after including all your css

Answer (score 1):

```
style.css line:5854

.breadcrumbs {
    padding: 16px 0;
    background: #92278f; <-- change this.
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.875em;
}
```

**NOTE**. I'm not sure if your theme uses SASS, but if it does you'll need to change the SASS file rather than the compiled CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to update the styles in PHP you will have to use inline styling to achieve the colour change. This isn't recommended as you'll end up in a whole world of hurt if you try to change it in the CSS in future.

You will need to find where your breadcrumb nav code lives in your code and then add something like this:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs" style="background-color: yellow;">
```

A much safer way to change the background colour would be to use CSS, as @alex-thomas has mentioned.

```
.breadcrumbs {
    background-color: yellow;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('wp_head', 'wh_BreadcrumbsCSS');

function wh_BreadcrumbsCSS()
{
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .breadcrumbs {
            background: #d6df23;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

Hope this helps!